# How to get JavaScript console error for debugging

Tags: javascript, angularjs, console, window

I am working on an Web Application. I want to capture the console error when network is down or network is slow and response coming from the server is getting slow or taking time.

Is there any way to capture JavaScript console error and use it with AngularJS?

Ex. `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to capture the errors on client side using techniques like,

```
window.onerror = function(errorMsg, url, lineNumber) {  
  //crash reporting to server 
};
```

and send them periodically to server. You can use the local store if you are planning to hold the error before sending to server. Alternately, there are few crash reporting commercial solution like jslogger or google analytics which can be leveraged for this.